# Exit code 100. Too many semaphores

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a C# program in Visual Studio 2012 and I have a problem.
Here's my code fragment:

```
Process proc = new Process();

proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\regasm.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "Absolute\\path\\to\\File.dll /codebase /tlb";
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();

MessageBox.Show("Exit code: "+proc.ExitCode);
proc.Close();
```

The problem is, when I build a Debug binary and run it, it works just great. Launches regasm.exe, registers the DLL, generates the .tlb file and it's all dandy.

But when I run a Release binary, nothing works and the MessageBox shows me "Exit code: 100". I looked it up but haven't really found anything useful at all.

---

Found my solution here: http://objectmix.com/dotnet/320921-regasm-tlb-complaints-element-not-found.html

RegAsm.exe error was like this:

```
RegAsm : error RA0000 : Type library exporter encountered an error while
processing 'Ruby2net.IRuby2net, Ruby2net'. Error: Element not found.
```

It looks like it was because I accidentally used the same `GUID` twice in my program. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Does the account you're attempting to run `regasm.exe` on have administrator privileges?

Comment: Did you find this? http://adamserrata.blogspot.com/2008/12/regasm-and-gac-fun-msb3217-and-ra0000.html

Comment: `"runas"` should attempt to elevate if not admin, iirc

Comment: also, 100 appears to always be process exit code, regardless of the error.  but regasm does print out an error message, so maybe you need to watch stderr and see what comes out.

Comment: @JohnGardner: He didn't mention the elevation, and maybe you don't need it if it's a debug build.  But you're right, getting the actual error message would be nice.

Comment: I'm guessing administrator privileges too, but FYI, you can use @ in front of strings to make it literal without slash being escape character, e.g. `@"C:\windows\notepad.exe"`

Comment: Windows is always asking for administrator privileges when my program is trying to run regasm.exe and I allow it, regardless of the build.

Comment: @Janisimo, check the project bitness (AnyCPU, x86, x64), is it different between Debug and Release configurations?

Comment: @Noseratio did that. It's the same on everything (AnyCPU)

Comment: @Janisimo, try x64 for both and see if that helps. And use `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe`, it's for x64.

Comment: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe` is for x86.

Comment: @Noseratio I tried x86 on everything. My OS is 32bit. No luck

Comment: So what does `RegAsm.exe` say when you run it manually against your Release DLL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be such a stupid mistake, as always...

The problem was that I used the same GUID in two places, a simple error when copying and pasting. Thank you all for your precious time.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of Google hits for "regasm exit code 100", just have a look-see.

Regasm *will* display an error message, you just can't see it because the console window immediately closes.  You need to keep it open so you can read the error message.  Do so by running cmd.exe with the /k option (keep).  Roughly:

```
        var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\regasm.exe \"Absolute\\path\\to\\File.dll\" /codebase /tlb";
        proc.Start();
```